# How to install the real Thunderbird on Debian wheezy?

Tags: executable, debian, crunchbang, thunderbird

I have Crunchbang 64 bit, a debian wheezy distro. Debian have a rebranded Firefox called Iceweasel and a rebranded Thunderbird called Icedove. But I don't want any of them.

I was able to install the latest version of Firefox by adding Linux Mint repo, and installing it from there. I did the same and installed Thunderbird, but it tells me that I'm not using the latest version, I need to download it from their site.

I downloaded it from the site and when i run

`sudo sh run-mozilla.sh` I get `run-mozilla.sh: Cannot execute`

I tried different commands, none worked. Do I need to `chmod` it?

Comment: Two things: 1) why `sudo`; 2) what's wrong with Debian's rebranded packages which are built from the same sources with just a different set of icons?

Comment: As @peterph said, icedove is the same as Thunderbird. They just use different icons (because of the license Mozilla uses for the icons). And because they're using different icons they are not allowed to call it Thunderbird anymore. But everything else is the same. So where is the point in downloading the binaries from Mozilla? That just increases the work to keep the software up-to-date. (which is very critical for that kind of software!)

Comment: The reason why it doesn't work might easily be, that you have a 64bit system and the Mozilla binaries are only 32bit - you'd need to install 32bit-compatibility packages. But really - just use IceDove/IceWeasel/IceApe (the last one is rebranded Seamonkey).

Comment: It might be a good idea to show us the permissions of the file when asking if you need to `chmod` it :).

Comment: @peterph The problem isn't the rebranding, but finding the right versions of your favorite extensions for the older version on icedove packaged in stable.

Comment: @jordanm afaik, Mike Hommey (Debian Mozilla maintainer) always packages something that is still supported by the upstream - in this case you may not have TB24 yet, but TB17, which is still supported. The extensions shouldn't be a problem, if it worked with 17.0.x, it's going to work with 17.0.y (or it is badly broken).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, don't add mint repositories to Debian, not a good idea. Mint is based on Ubuntu which, while based on Debian, is not 100% compatible with Debian repositories. Mixing them is likely to cause trouble. Instead, add LMDE (Linux Mint Debian Edition) [repositories](http://packages.linuxmint.com/list.php?release=Debian). LMDE *is* Debian and is 100% compatible with the Debian repos. **As long as you're running Debian testing**, that should work with no problems.

Second, as others have pointed out, this is really truly not worth the effort.

Anyway, the error you get is actually

```
run-mozilla.sh: Cannot execute .
```

The `.` is important, it shows that the script expects an argument and since you don't give it one, it takes the current directory. The script is not an installer and is usually called by another script, not directly.

To install the thunderbird binaries, follow the instructions [here](https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/installing-thunderbird-linux#w_downloading-the-thunderbird-archive):

```
wget 'http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/thunderbird/releases/3.1.4/linux-i686/en-US/thunderbird-3.1.4.tar.bz2 -O- | ' sudo tar xj -C /opt && sudo ln -s /opt/thunderbird/thunderbird /usr/bin/thunderbird
```

However, this will install the 32bit thunderbird which won't work on a 64bit system unless you have multiarch installed. You will also need to bring in the dependencies manually. Please don't do this, either install the [deb from LMDE](http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/import/t/thunderbird/thunderbird-l10n-ar_31.3.0~linuxmint1+betsy_amd64.deb) or just use icedove which is thunderbird with different icons.

Comment: Adding LMDE, which is based on testing, will hose his system if he is running stable.

Comment: @jordanm true, caveat added, thanks. Still, that would be no worse than if he adds a Mint one.

Comment: @terdon cheer for your answer, your link there is broken.