# Repeated Thunderbird freeze/crash on Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, thunderbird

Last week I've installed Thunderbird on a new Debian Jessie system using [this -- without Multiarch; instability fears](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/how-to-install-the-real-thunderbird-on-debian-wheezy). From my previous system (Ubuntu 14.04) I've copied my Thunderbird profile directory into `.thunderbird/` and redirected the `profiles.ini`towards it. Sometimes everything works fine.

However, often Thunderbird just crashes. Don't know if it is related but two times also the system friezed entirely. Maybe this is related to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220562/debian-jessie-randomly-freezes#) -- but have not enough reputation to make comments.

Here is the output of the terminal started Thunderbird.

```
_@_:/usr/thunderbird$ ./thunderbird-bin
1470683962553   addons.xpi  WARN    Exception running bootstrap method startup on {fe272bd1-5f76-4ea4-8501-a05d35d823fc}: ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side (resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/_/.thunderbird/5aibcqp1.default/extensions/%7Bfe272bd1-5f76-4ea4-8501-a05d35d823fc%7D.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> jar:file:///home/_/.thunderbird/5aibcqp1.default/extensions/%7Bfe272bd1-5f76-4ea4-8501-a05d35d823fc%7D.xpi!/lib/ui.js:407:5) JS Stack trace: require@bootstrap.js:141:4 < @main.js:19:1 < require@bootstrap.js:141:4 < startup@bootstrap.js:28:2 < this.XPIProvider.callBootstrapMethod@XPIProvider.jsm:4663:9 < this.XPIProvider.startup@XPIProvider.jsm:2734:13 < callProvider@AddonManager.jsm:227:12 < _startProvider@AddonManager.jsm:833:5 < AddonManagerInternal.startup@AddonManager.jsm:1016:9 < this.AddonManagerPrivate.startup@AddonManager.jsm:2782:5 < amManager.prototype.observe@addonManager.js:58:7
[calBackendLoader] Using libical backend at /home/_/.thunderbird/5aibcqp1.default/extensions/{e2fda1a4-762b-4020-b5ad-a41df1933103}/components/libical-manifest
2016-08-08 21:19:52 autosyncActivities  ERROR   onDownloadCompleted: TypeError: this._syncInfoPerFolder[folder.URI] is undefined
```

Comment: For a start run thnderird from a terminal.  It does output a couple of things (and the libraries it links to also output some stuff to STDOUT/STDERR).  This will give you (and us) a rough idea of what it could be.

Comment: @grochmal Thank you much for your advice. Please read the [UPDATE]. Would be nice if you offer a short solution if you agree on my guess or have an alternative explanation. I will check it and rate you up. Best wishes.

Comment: I actually know pretty little about thunderbird.  All I know is that it is built on top of firefox's/mozilla's XUL (which is what is printing those messages to the terminal).  All I said was a generic way to debug problems on *nix :). Now, If you can find the specific plugin that caused the crash (by enabling them one by one) you can add a self answer that may be able to help other people.  Because of `libical` it looks like some Calendar app, but I cannot tell, I do not use thunderbird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the advice of **grochmal** I've started Thunderbird from the terminal -- see comments above.

```
$ cd /usr/thunderbird/
$ ./thunderbird-bin
```

I've remarked some possible issues with the profile add-ons. (Keep in mind, I've hard-copied the profile folder from an Ubuntu 14.04 system.)

Following I deactivated and removed add-ons with warnings and/or errors. Inside Thunderbird click:

```
Menu (horizontal |||) > Add-ons Manager
```

Thunderbird seems stable since.